# Background color of one cell the same as another cell, but keeping the value

Tags: excel, vba

How can I achieve that one cell has the same color as another cell, but I need to keep the value?

Example: In cell A1 I have a value (e.g. 21.14) and  I want that background color of cell A1 is the same as in cell F1. Background color of F1 is determined by some other conditional formatting, but I really cannot find a way to transfer only color from F1 to A1. Background color of A2 should be the same as F2 and so one...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the Format Painter it copies the conditional formatting rule.

Comment: No, Format Painter is working only if background color is set manually and not via Conditional Formatting (at least not in my case).

Comment: It does copy it. If you use it and then click on Conditional Formatting (for A1) and Manage Rules you can see the rule recreated. Perhaps the original CF uses a formula with absolute cell referencing, so that the rule is no longer met?

Comment: BTW How is this a programming question? It belongs on superuser if there is no programming involved.

Comment: @AndyG I was going to say instead Adjust the conditional formatting rule to meet the needs of the new cell.

Comment: @AndyG Non programming questions are allowed.  I would not say this one does not qualify, but that is why there is an excel-formula tags.  Enough formulas and complex formulas can be equivalent to programming and achieve the same results.

Comment: Yes @ForwardEd I would have said that (about Adjust) ;) after discovering why it didn't appear to copy across. In response to your second post, I am aware that formula solutions and questions can appear here, there is no formula involved. It is currently a simple formatting question.

Comment: Get the interior color of **F1** using `Range("F1").DisplayFormat` and apply it to cell **A1**

Comment: and there is Gary with the programming answer 8)  Thank you Gary!

Comment: Every Excel question could be given a programming answer :)